# Record Call in android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to record call in my android application but when I use UPLINK, DOWNLINK  as audio source both time it record voice  from the MIC. When I used VOICE_CALL it produced noise in recording, is it bug or can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK , Call recording is not possible in Android, refer this

1. http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c2bc85eb60ae2aa5?pli=1
2. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117#c226

Comment: @Nirav: To gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, accepts the good answers of your questions

Comment: @SankarGanesh I know you have posted on jan 2011 but plz see this: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.androglobe.androrec&feature=apps_topselling_free