# How to record call in android

Tags: android

i want to record both incoming and outgoing calls. is it possible in android.

i don't want to use Speaker mode. want without MIC.

i search a lot of but there is nothing to seems work.

please give me suggestion.

Comment: check out this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839297/record-call-in-android-2-2


Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not record call in all handsets. Only in handsets which allowed the api to record voice call, you will be able to record a call. in those handsets you can set the audiosource of mediarecorder by using following.

MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK | MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK )

Comment: About the audio source, combining `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK | MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK` will result in the same value of `VOICE_DOWNLINK` , because `VOICE_DOWNLINK` is 3 and `VOICE_UPLINK` is 2 . You are not supposed to use those as flags. Only one is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think this links will help you...

[link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/264740/How-to-record-calls-in-Android)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603113/record-call-in-android)

[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839297/record-call-in-android-2-2)

Thanks....